# how to change the body's border radius in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, document-body

I want to change the border radius of the first div container that has class .container-fluid , how I can do that using bootstrap [body's border radius in Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d535f.png)

Comment: Since we can't debug the image you posted, post a minimal code snippet. (btw, I just tried with boostrap 3.3.7 and it works just fine)

Comment: i posted in a the comment below , here it is https://codepen.io/manafnn/pen/JJmMWG?editors=1100

Comment: Here it is with rounded corner: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXdGPq

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your content in `<div>` and apply border-radius to wrapper

UPD: Add following to your css code

```
body > .container-fluid:first-child {
    border-radius: 20px; //for example
}
```

Comment: Could you add a fiddle with an example please or at least edit you post with some code.

Comment: hey thanks for the replay, I already had everything in devs i tried that with main one but unfortunately it dosen't work, i will put it

Comment: With @Skribja code the `border-radius` apply right https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwexrv?editors=1100

Comment: I tried to do all things with html and bootstrap and use a lettal of html but it seams that i cant do it with bootstrap. so thanks for the helping i apreceat it

Comment: @Manaf https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/borders/, but this is v4

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your custom css:

```css
.rounded-xl {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```

and use it on your `<row>` elements in place of the usual bootstrap [`border`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-radius) class.

#### Example

```
<div class="row rounded-xl">
<div>
```